# Mullvad vpn won't connect on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: vpn

Mullvad vpn won't connect and I keep receiving this error of no server found. any suggestions that would help

Comment: More details please...

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 1):

I made [a client version using WireGuard](https://github.com/adihrustic/Mullvad-WireGuard-script) some time ago.

The developers behind Mullvad have previously stated that: ["WireGuard is the future"](https://mullvad.net/en/blog/2017/9/27/wireguard-future/). Which made me invest time into actualizing a user friendly version of WireGuard with Mullvad.

If you're interested have a look!

Answer (score 0):

I reached out to Mullvad support because I had the same issue. They told me to use OpenVPN or wireguard while they work on a brand new client.

Here's the link they pointed me to: https://mullvad.net/en/guides/linux-openvpn-installation/

Make sure you use the Android config file and not the linux one (seems backwards to me too but it works).

Also the dns setting in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf wasn't there for me so I just ignored that step and it worked for me. Hopefully the client gets released soon.